# Owl Carousel(2.2.1) - Button next and Previous dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have problem with my Owl Carousel which doesnt work. It is normaly display at my website but buttons next and previous dont work.

I am not sure where could be mistake. Everything seems to be Ok.

Thank you.

```
<ul class="tab-list owl-carousel nav-style7 nav-center-center owl-theme owl-loaded">




<div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-1522px, 0px, 0px); transition: 0s; width: 4870.4px;"><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 304.4px; margin-right: 0px;"><li>
                        <img src="#">
                        <a class="overlay" href="#" target="_blank">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                <p>insta 2</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 304.4px; margin-right: 0px;"><li>
                        <img src="#">
                        <a class="overlay" href="#" target="_blank">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                <p>insta 3</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 304.4px; margin-right: 0px;"><li>
                        <img src="#">
                        <a class="overlay" href="#" target="_blank">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                <p>insta 4</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 304.4px; margin-right: 0px;"><li>
                        <img src="#">
                        <a class="overlay" href="#" target="_blank">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                <p>insta 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 304.4px; margin-right: 0px;"><li>
                        <img src="#">
                        <a class="overlay" href="#" target="_blank">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                <p>insta 6</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 304.4px; margin-right: 0px;"><li>
                        <img src="#">
                        <a class="overlay" href="#" target="_blank">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                <p>insta 1</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 304.4px; margin-right: 0px;"><li>
                        <img src="#">
                        <a class="overlay" href="#" target="_blank">
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                <p>insta 5</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li></div></div></div><div class="owl-controls"><div class="owl-nav"><div class="owl-prev" style="">prev</div><div class="owl-next" style="">next</div></div><div class="owl-dots" style="display: none;"></div></div></ul>
```

And here is my JavaScript code which i use. I am not sure if I use it at the right way.

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
```

Comment: First things first: Never (ever) post the "processed" code. The HTML you have on your question was already processed by Owl carousel, which prevents us from helping you correctly. Having said this, it seems to be working correctly (see https://jsfiddle.net/milz/psvd5f03/). However, it would be better if you just use divs instead of ul/li, because you'll end up with invalid code (you can't have a div as a direct child of a ul, in valid HTML)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, yeah it works in jsfiddle, but on my web it doesnt work, I have just static pictures. I cant find mistake.

Comment: I found the my mistake, it was in posting the owl-carousel html throught javascript.